# Handling item visibilty in grid view

Tags: android, gridview, google-cloud-firestore

I am retrieving images from firebase firestore collection into grid image view. but i want to show only images that has the current user id and hide the rest by setting visibility to gone but this messes up the view by leaving blank (white) spaces between images.

this is were i try to hide view in my adapter

```
if (convertView == null)
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.image_grid_view, null);

    ImageView postImage =  convertView.findViewById(R.id.my_store_posts);

    Posts e = new Posts();
    e = postList.get(position);

    //final String title = e.getTitle();
    final String image = e.getImage_url();

    String uid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();

    if (e.getUser_id().equals(uid)) {

        Picasso.with(context).load(image).into(postImage);
    }else {
        postImage.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    return convertView;
}
}
```

this is my layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MyStoreActivity">

<GridView
    android:id="@+id/my_store_grid"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:numColumns="3"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="parent"
     />
```

layout for adapter

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/my_store_posts"
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="150dp"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/default_avatar" />
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try to hide the whole view:**

```
if (e.getUser_id().equals(uid)) {

    convertView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    Picasso.with(context).load(image).into(postImage);

}else {
    convertView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
```

Comment: I tried that and it did not work